# Flex: 3 элемента 1 по центру остальные по краям

Tags: css, flexbox

Пытаюсь сделать верстку на флексах, есть три контейнера разной ширины.
Два должны быть по краям и один по центру.

Пока-что поулчается только сделать крайние контейнеры фиксированной ширины и поставить `justify-contnent: space-between;` но этот вариант не подходит т.к. для адаптивной верстки центральный блок пропадает и уже надо менять эти значения ширины краев чтобы хватало место на содержимое.

[image]

Comment: Вы можете использовать JavaScript и при определённом размере менять значение `justify-content`. Мне кажется, это гораздо проще, чем писать тонны CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл способ для разных элементов. Надеюсь, это Вам поможет:

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.block {
  background-color: red;
}

.first {
  width: 25px;
}

.mid {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.last {
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block first"></div>
  <div class="block mid"></div>
  <div class="block last"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать обычный флекс из пяти блоков. А между 3-мя основными, сделать 2 пустых, которые будут обеспечивать только ширину.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/m69ob753/) (там можно растягивать окно - смотреть)

```css
.mama {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff200;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #880015;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.center {
  width: 40%;  
  min-width: 200px;
}
.mid {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="block center"></div>  
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам может помочь свойство `justify-content`. Значение `space-between` первый и последний элементы прижмёт к краям, а оставшиеся равномерно распределит.

```css
.block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**UPD:**
Способ только для элементов одинаковой ширины.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/s3tm0apn/ - и правда)

Comment: Да, но тогда центральный элемент будет не по центру!

Comment: Да, действительно, это хорошо работает, только если элементы равны. Попробую поискать что-нибудь ещё.